# shared_ptr not changing object (Visual studio 2012)

Tags: pointers, visual-studio-2012, shared-ptr, shared

I have a really strange problem. I can't modify the object I am pointing to with a shared_ptr.

Example code:

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo
{
public:
    int asd;
    foo(){}
    ~foo(){}
};


 void d(shared_ptr<foo> c)
{
    c->asd = 3;
}

void main()
{
    foo a;
    a.asd = 5;
    d(make_shared<foo>(a));
    cout<<a.asd; //asd is still 5
}
```

As far as I know you can access the object pointed to by the shared_ptr by using the "->" operator, so what am I doing wrong here? How can I change the asd variable inside the class via the shared pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c++
// create a temporary object by copying a
// the shared pointer you pass to d function actually points to this temporary object
d(make_shared<foo>(a));

// allocate and store foo object in shared_ptr instead
auto p_a(make_shared<foo>());
p_a->asd = 3;
d(p_a);
```

Comment: I am not sure if I undrestand it correctly, but I made the following changes:

foo a;
 a.asd = 5;
 auto p(make_shared<foo>(a));
 d(p);
 cout<<a.asd;

but it still doesn't work...

Comment: As i wrote above, expression `make_shared<foo>(a)` creates a shared pointer that points to a temporary object, not at `a`. `make_shared` always creates a new object and returns a shared pointer pointing to this new object, it does not make a shared pointer to existing object.

Comment: I see, so how can I make a shared pointer to the existing object?

Comment: Making a shared pointer (or any other type of smart pointer) to a stack allocated object is not possible because they won't be able to control the lifetime of that object since it will be destroyed when it goes out of scope. Actually even if you pass a pointer to a stack allocated object into shared ptr then you will end up with a dangling pointer.

Comment: So basically it is not possible to change the contents of  an object being pointed by any type of smart pointer?

Comment: The general rule is that change of object ownership kind always indicates an error. You can not keep the same object on stack in shared pointer or in unique pointer at the same time. Upd: you are free to change the contents of an object being pointed to. But you can not make shared_pointer to point at stack object.

Answer (score 0):

> *... so what am I doing wrong here?*

From [cppreference on `std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) [**emphasis** mine]:

> ```
> template< class T, class... Args >
> shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
> ```
>
> Constructs an object of type `T` and wraps it in a `std::shared_ptr`
>   **using `args` as the parameter list for the constructor of `T`**.

In your case, you supply an instance of `foo` as argument to `std::make_shared`, which will be used when *constructing a new object* of type `foo`; i.e., making use of the default supplied copy CTOR of `foo` (`foo(const foo&)`). This new object will be a temporary and only live for the call to `d(...)`.